# pip not updating to newest version

Tags: pip

When I run `pip install -U pip` it doesn't install the newer version.

```
drahcir@Altair:~/dev$ pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
drahcir@Altair:~/dev$ pip install -U pip
Downloading/unpacking pip
  Downloading pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB): 1.2MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip
Cleaning up...
drahcir@Altair:~/dev$ pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Even though it says it downloaded pip 8.1.2, the pip version still says 1.5.6

How can I get pip to upgrade to 8.1.2?

Comment: How did you initially install `pip`?

Comment: Ubuntu comes bundled with python and pip

Answer (score 1):

This is incredibly old, but just in case it helps. When I had the same issue, I went into my venv Lib\site-packages folder (I am guessing for you that'd be usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages) and found that I had two pip folders because the folder for the old version of pip had not been deleted during installation. Once I manually deleted the folder for the old version, pip started working as desired.